What is the shape of neutron star?
What would be the shape of a fast spinning neutron star?
Can it be a disk?
Or just a Saturn-like ring?
Or would it take the shape of the sun?

How does spinning affect the shape of pulsars? says “Even with their very strong magnetic fields and their relativistic spins, they're very likely a more perfect sphere than anything else we've ever found, macroscopically, in the entire Universe.”

A related question on our sister site: Shape of neutron stars.

Almost spherical. How precisely do you want to define "almost"?
